# Download only email subject in JavaMail & imaps

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to download only **subject** of emails, because it should take less time (downloading ~10 emails with photos take about 10 min :/).

Code that I'm now using is:

```
    try {
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(...);

        Folder folder = store.getFolder(folderName);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        message = folder.getMessages();

        for (Message m : message) {
            System.out.println(m.getSubject());
        }

        folder.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to me that you should look into prefetching the messages with:

```
FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
fp.add("Subject");
folder.fetch(message, fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing will download the entire message envelope (but **not** the entire message), which includes the subject and the recipients.  That's usually pretty cheap to download.  If you really want only the subject because you're never going to look at the other information, you need to deal with the raw header using something like this:

```
String rawvalue = msg.getHeader("Subject", null);

if (rawvalue == null)
        return null;

try {
        return MimeUtility.decodeText(MimeUtility.unfold(rawvalue));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        return rawvalue;
}
```

The folder.fetch call described in the other answer will allow you to prefetch all the Subject headers in one operation, instead of fetching each one as you process that message.  You can also prefetch the entire envelope if you decide that's what you want; see the javadocs for details.

Comment: All I want to do is optimize downloading email. How can I download entire message envelope?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, let me try again...  The envelope will be downloaded on demand, for each message, when you access some part of that message for which the envelope is needed.  If you want to "prefetch" all the envelopes for a bunch of messages, in bulk, in advance of accessing them, see the other answer (Folder.fetch method).  Does that help?